# List printer function flexibility

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, printing

I am writing a program in Python 3 and I have a function which prints out all the items in a list and also receives, verifies and returns user inputs.

```
def printer(my_list):
  for item in range(len(my_list)):
    print("{}. {}",format(item + 1, my_list[item]))
```

This is a simplified version, it prints out each list item and labels them numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. I would like to have a Boolean parameter for my function called `label` and if this is `False` then the printer would not print each item out `1. List item 1, 2. List Item 2` etc. but instead `List item 1, List item 2`, etc. Whereas if it is `True` it will print each item with a labelled index.

Comment: OK, so just *do that*. What's your question?

Comment: I don't know how to make a parameter change the way the items are formatted. i.e from print("{}. {}",format(item + 1, my_list[item])) to print("{}"format(my_list[item]))

Comment: Add a parameter, pass in a `bool`, use that in an `if` branch? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What are the branches in this if statement?

Comment: What are you asking me for? You're the one that knows what the requirements are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def printer(my_list, label=True):
#check if label is True
    if label:
        for number,item in enumerate(my_list):
            print number+1, item  #print labeled index (+1 to begin with 1) & item
    else:
        for item in my_list:
            print item #print items only
```

Example:

```
>>> mylist = ["monkey","donkey","dog"]
>>> printer(mylist)
1 monkey
2 donkey
3 dog

>>> printer(mylist, label=False)
monkey
donkey
dog
```